# Three.js scene stringify fails

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, three.js

Stringifying three.js editor scene object fails with Range error - invalid string length. So we tried to get the keys of the scene object and stringified it each of them separately and tried to send it to the server using WebSockets, but it failed with max payload size exceeded error.any help on sending this huge scene object to the server will be appreciated

Comment: Rather than sending the entire scene, why not just send relevant data for your server process? This could be anything from just the IDs and transformation matrices, to the geometry buffers. But trying to send the entire object(s) as a string sounds really bad. If you _must_ send the whole scene, then look into writing it to a transmission format, like JSON or GLTF.

Comment: When it is stringified,the length is huge that it results in invalid range error. My intention is to have the scene details send to the server as json intially when the user save the 3d project first time and later on delta json changes to be send to server and applied to the intial json to save the data corresponding to the   edits to the project